# objective c regex convert match to uppercase before replacing

Tags: objective-c, regex, uppercase

Consider the following code

```
NSString* originalString = @"I love regex. regex is cool.";
NSString* regexString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"(regex)"];
NSString* replaceWithString = @"[$1]";
NSString* finalString = [htmlString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfRegex:regexString withString:replaceWithString];
```

The output is:

> I love [regex]. [regex] is cool.

What I wants instead is

> I love [REGEX]. [REGEX] is cool.

i.e, to toUpperCase() of the $1 type group matches.

It appears that I can do this using `replacementStringForResult:inString:offset:template:` but don't know how. Can someone kindly help.

Comment: I don't know if this will work for you, but in many languages, you can use `\u\1` or perhaps `\u$1`

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve what you want with [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/) like this:

```
upper = [originalString stringByMatching:@"(regex)"
                        replace:RKReplaceAll
                        withReferenceString:@"[\\U$1\\E]"]; 
// I love [REGEX]. [REGEX] is cool.
```

References:

- [RegexKit](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/)
- [NSString RegexKit Additions Reference](http://regexkit.sourceforge.net/Documentation/NSString.html)

Comment: oh i thought NSRegularExpression has made RegexKit obsolete!! Lets wait for someone to answer if its possible using standard Apple APIs instead of RegexKit